# Rstudio error: the table must the same classes in the same order

Tags: r, knn, confusion-matrix

I keep getting this error:  *the table must the same classes in the same order*
when implementing **KNN and confusion matrix** to **get the accuracy**

```
df_train <- df_trimmed_n[1:10,]
df_test <- df_trimmed_n[11:20,]

df_train_labels <- df_trimmed[1:10, 1]
df_test_labels <- df_trimmed[11:20, 1]

library(class)
library(caret)
df_knn<-knn(df_train,df_test,cl=df_train_labels,k=10)
confusionMatrix(table(df_knn,df_test_labels))

Error in confusionMatrix.table(table(df_knn, df_test_labels)) : 
  the table must the same classes in the same order

> print(df_knn)
 [1] 28134 5138  4820  3846  1216  1885  1885  22021 5138  15294
Levels: 106 1216 1885 3846 4820 5138 15294 22021 22445 28134
> print(df_test_labels)
 [1] 33262  6459  5067  7395 22720  1217  3739    84 16219 17819

> table(df_knn,df_test_labels)
       df_test_labels
df_knn  84 1217 3739 5067 6459 7395 16219 17819 22720 33262
  106    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
  1216   0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     1     0
  1885   0    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
  3846   0    0    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0
  4820   0    0    0    1    0    0     0     0     0     0
  5138   0    0    0    0    1    0     1     0     0     0
  15294  0    0    0    0    0    0     0     1     0     0
  22021  1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
  22445  0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     0
  28134  0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0     1
```

evn though both knn and test dataset have the same number of rows=10 but i'm not too sure **what is wrong with the same classes and order?**

Comment: It looks like they must be the same class. It appears that one is a factor, the other seems numeric. You can also use the result of function ```table``` inside ```confusionMatrix```.

Comment: That's what i did, using the `table` inside `confusionMatrix` and getting the error
Any suggestion how to go around the factor thing?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay close attention. Actually, confusion matrices are for two-class categorical variables.